# Why are all $document functions undefined in my test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

I have directive in AngularJS which contain the module $document.

```
$document.click(function (e) {});
```

I've been try to write unit test for it using Karma and it break the test because the function `click()` not exist in `$document`, also try with other functions of `$document` like `keyup()` and got the same problem:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This is the test code which make it fail:

```
describe('Directive: multiSelectMenu', function () {

    var element, scope;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    describe('Test setup', function() {
        it ('Injecting required data', inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            element = $compile(angular.element('<div multi-select-menu></div>'))(scope);

            $rootScope.$apply();

            scope = element.isolateScope();
            scope.$apply();
        }));
    });
});
```

Why does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document) says about $document:

> A [jQuery or jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) wrapper for the browser's window.document object.

And if you click on the link, you'll see the methods defined on a jqLite element. Neither click() not keyup() are among them. These methods do exist on a real jQuery object (see http://api.jquery.com/category/events/), but AngularJS will only return a jQuery object if you include jQuery, before angular.js, in your list of JS files.

Comment: But event when i loaded jQuery before Angular, on Karma it seems like $document comes empty without any method.